# How to get video size of compressed video by ffmpeg?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

Hi we are using ffmpeg for compressing the video through php script, now what i need is i want to get the video size of compressed image, but am getting an video path so kindly guide me how i need to over come this?

Below is the code what i used for compressing the video

original path

```
$path = "sample.mp4";
```

Command to compress

```
exec("ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 compressed_video.mp4);
```

The command what i used for getting video size

```
$compressed_video_information = exec("ls -h1 compressed_video.mp4);
echo $compressed_video_information;
```

I get just file path instaed of getting video file size, so someone help me how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-h` option (ex: ls -lh) displays size in human readable form(KB/MB/GB etc..)

```
exec("ls -lh compressed_video.mp4",$out);// pass file path here
$size=explode(' ',$out[0]);
print_r($size[4]);
```

Comment: Thanks i got the output as per as i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP function [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php):

```
<?php
$filesize_in_bytes = filesize('compressed_video.mp4');
```

Comment: this will take some more time for my execution.

Comment: It's also return 0 if file size is more then 2GB

Comment: @ManiKandan: if time is of importance then use `du`, as in `du compressed_video.mp4`. It's twice as fast as using `ls -lh`. However, I'm not sure how execution time of `filesize` can hinder you if the impact of it on the total execution time of your script will be of no significance; converting video will take a lot longer. It's also just as fast as using `ls`. @Saty: in the question no indication is made about the size of the resulting video files. A native PHP solution is also more robust, as the use of `ls` with exploding of the result depends on the configuration of the OS.